# Loss of power below 15 mph

Tags: troubleshooting, subaru, forester, power-loss

This is a Subaru Forester 2003.

The car start losing power after a few minutes on the road. And suddenly lost all power and is almost impossible to drive.

Already changed:

- fuel pump
- spark plugs
- ignition coil
- O2 sensor
- fuel filter

The car had no check engine codes. The catalytic converter is new, less than 3 years old.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: When you say there's no check engine codes does that mean that there's no check engine light on the dash, or that you've read the OBD codes using a reader?

Comment: Completely random guess, but did you check the earth straps. There should be a braided cable on each head, connecting the engine to the body. If one or both are missing, weird things can happen. They're often overlooked, and broken/torn off if the engine is removed without them being disconnected.

Comment: Has no Check engine codes at this moment, a while ago had the p0447 code which was a broken cable and the p0420 that says Catalyst System Efficiency Below Threshold) bank1. And the O2 code but I already replace the sensor already. Right now doesn't show any codes

Comment: Do you have any way to test fuel pressure ?

Comment: No, but when the car was losing power I take it to the mechanic and they test the fuel pressure, and told me that was a bad fuel pump, which I thought that was the problem. So i change the fuel pump 2 weeks ago and when I went to the road start givings me problems again. Same

Answer (score 1):

Catalytic converters can go bad pretty quickly when engines are out of tune. p0420 is possibly that.

The definitive test is a pressure gauge where the O2 sensor is.

If the compression on the motor is good (compression test) you need to look elsewhere.  If compression is low on all cylinders - timing belt jumped a tooth.

Vacuum gauge will also give you an idea.  If, at idle, the vacuum slowly goes to zero, you are no longer 'pumping air' and also points to a clog.

I had one motor loose power when 3 rocker arms jumped off (Chrsler 4.7, overhead cam)  Compression check was weird, leak down test was also weird.  I suspect owner didn't change the oil often enough and hydraulic adjusters (like lifters) were all coked up/clogged.  Reved it too much when cold....   No noise from engine, no check engine line, just way down on power.